# TensorFlow Python - Is there a way to insert a tensorflow_datasets dataset into ImageGenerator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0

I have been trying for a long time to use data augmentation in the tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageGenerator function, but every example I have seen passes in a directory with the files. My goal is to use tensorflow_datasets to import MNIST and then pass that to the data augmentation function, but I haven't been able to find out how.

I am willing to use a directory if it is easier and if anyone can find an easy way to do that, and successfully explain to me how to do that.

See code below

Thank you, Max

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

def main():
    data, info = tfds.load("mnist", with_info=True)
    train_data, test_data = data['train'], data['test']

    image_gen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        rotation_range=20,
        width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        fill_mode='nearest')

    #
    # What Do I Do Here??
    #

    # train_data_gen = image_gen.flow(data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've spent a large part of this morning trying to figure out what--if either of these methods--is the "correct" way to handle data loading *AND* augmentation in TF2. So much for ["TensorFlow 2.0 removes redundant APIs"](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/effective_tf2), right? My current understanding is that these two data loading methods are *independent* and meant to be used *separately* (though it would be great if someone from TF could chime in here).

First, [`ImageDataGenerator`](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) generates batches of tensor image data with *real-time* data augmentation. I've seen some solutions that use `tfds` to read a dataset into a numpy array an `ImageDataGenerator`, but I'd be shocked if that wasn't an anti-pattern. My understanding is that if you use `ImageDataGenerator`, you should be using it to both load and preprocess your data.

I've opted to go with the official(maybe?!) [`tensorflow_datasets`](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets) route. Rather than leverage the built-in augmentations in `ImageDataGenerator`, I use `tfds.load` to load a dataset and then a combination of caching and [`map` calls](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset?version=stable#map) to do my preprocessing.

First we load our data using the S3 API:

```
train_size = 45000
val_size = 5000
(train, val, test), info = tfds.load(
    "cifar10:3.*.*",
    as_supervised=True,
    split=[
        "train[0:{}]".format(train_size),
        "train[{}:{}]".format(train_size, train_size + val_size),
        "test",
    ],
    with_info=True
)
```

Then, using a series of helpers and [`tf.image`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/image) functions, we can do preprocessing:

```
def _pad_image(
    image: tf.Tensor, label: tf.Tensor, padding: int = 4
) -> Tuple[tf.Tensor, tf.Tensor]:
    """Pads and image and returns a given supervised training pair."""
    image = tf.pad(
        image, [[padding, padding], [padding, padding], [0, 0]], mode="CONSTANT"
    )
    return image, label


def _crop_image(
    image: tf.Tensor, label: tf.Tensor, out_size: List[int] = None
) -> Tuple[tf.Tensor, tf.Tensor]:
    """Randomly crops an image and returns a given supervised training pair."""
    if out_size is None:
        out_size = [32, 32, 3]
    image = tf.image.random_crop(image, out_size)
    return image, label


def _random_flip(
    image: tf.Tensor, label: tf.Tensor, prob=0.5
) -> Tuple[tf.Tensor, tf.Tensor]:
    """Randomly flips an image and returns a given supervised training pair."""
    if tf.random.uniform(()) > 1 - prob:
        image = tf.image.flip_left_right(image)
    return image, label


processed_train = (
    train.map(_pad_image, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
    .cache()
    .map(_crop_image, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
    .map(_random_flip, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
)
```

Since we have a [`tf.data.Dataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset), we can then do batching, repeat, etc. using the standard API.